# How to model a dictionary (word with a definition) in Java

Tags: java, oop, dictionary

I'm trying to design some Java classes to represent the SentiWordNet dictionary.
In this particular dictionary every word has this structure:

PartOfSpeech PosScore NegScore Term Gloss(the term definition)

Example:

```
a    0.8    0   generous      willing to give and share unstintingly; "a generous donation"
```

I created a class DictionaryEntry, which represents the data structure of a single term of the dictionary (i.e. 5 attributes, one for each attribute of the dictionary), and a class Dictionary, that generates the entire dictionary, taking each word from the .txt containing the SentiWordNet dictionary.

I wonder if this could be a good implementation or if there is a better one; consider that Dictionary class has no attribute and only one method that load every term in a ArrayList...maybe I can avoid this class and load the dictionary in the main() method (which is in another class) or add another method to DictionaryEntry for this purpose...

Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: Could you explain the example in better detail? It didn't make sense to me

Comment: What is the purpose of a positive and negative score? Why not have a single score that goes positive and negative?

Comment: @Compass The presence of positive and negative score is a peculiarity of the SentiWordNet and measures the PN-polarity of a term, calcuted by a textual classifier. For the purpose of my project this is an unrelevant detail: positive and negative score are simply seen as two attributes.

Comment: @NicolaScafoni Just making sure! As long as it's intentional, no problem!

Comment: @Compass Ok! Thanks for being so scrupulous! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's an object oriented language.  I'd create an object that encapsulates the state and behavior you want:

```
public class DictionaryEntry {
    private String term;
    private String definition;
    private PartOfSpeech partOfSpeech; // a nice candidate for an enum
    private int positiveScore;
    private int negativeScore;
    // add methods.
}
```

I could see this as the value in a `Map<String, DictionaryEntry>` where term is the key.  A `HashMap` would give you `O(1)` lookups.

If the advice that "Java is an object-oriented language" is good for the entries, it's equally good for the `Dictionary`:

```
public class Dictionary {
    private Map<String, DictionaryEntry> entries;

    public Dictionary(InputStream corpus) throws IOException {
        this.entries = new HashMap<String, DictionaryEntry>();
        // Read the corpus and populate the map here.
    }

    public DictionaryEntry lookup(String term) { 
        return this.entries.get(term);
    }
}
```

None of your clients need know that you've chosen a `HashMap` as the underlying implementation for your `Dictionary`.  They just want to do lookups of terms from that corpus.

This is called encapsulation.  It means clients of your class can use it without having to know about the underlying details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My problem is not how to model the single term of the dictionary (DictionaryEntry class you posted is perfect for this purpose) but if I should create a Dictionary class with just one method that populates the HashMap (this class wouldn't do anything else) or if it's better to create the dictionary (again, as an HashMap) in the main() method of my project.

Comment: @NicolaScafoni in this case, I would recommend building a DictionaryFactory for a lack of a better term. If you need to re-instantiate or rebuild your library, then you can just create a new Factory. It's more portable as it makes the Dictionary itself independent of the main method for creation.

Comment: A factory is a virtual constructor.  It makes sense if she'll have several types of Dictionary, but in this case I think a constructor that can take different corpus files as input is sufficient.